# Is there any way to preserve unused classes in Dart?

Tags: spring, dart, dependency-injection, tree-shaking

I started developing my own dependency injection package in dart just for fun. The problem I came across is that when a class is in it's own file and is not imported anywhere, dart's tree shaking will remove it and make it inaccessible. This makes it impossible for me to map implementation of some interface to the interface so I cannot ask context to give me implementation when I supply the interface. Here is what I mean:

```
import 'context/context.dart';

void main() {
  Context context = Context();
  Interface interface = context.getInstance<Interface>();
  interface.works();
}

abstract class Interface {
  void works();
}
```

And here is the implementation of the "Interface" abstract class:

```
@Singleton()
class Implementation implements Interface {
  @override
  void works() {
    print('works');
  }
}
```

If I import the file that contains the "Implementation" class, context is able to find it and map it but I want to avoid doing that. Is there any way to turn off the tree shaking or preserve the class without importing it ?

Comment: What is the definition of `Context`?  If `Context` is using the `Implementation` class, then `Implementation` should not be tree-shaken out.

Comment: If it's being eliminated during tree shaking, then nothing in the current compilation is using it, and could never ever talk about it anyway.  I'm not seeing how you would end up newly needing to refer to something that wasn't referenced during the compilation.

Comment: I assume you are using `dart:mirrors` in `Context`. That won't work for ahead-of-time compiled code.

Comment: Context is basically the same concept as Spring context. Yes it is using mirrors to scan each library for classes annotated with @Singleton annotation. Then it checks if that class implements or extends some other class so it can map implementation to interface. But because of this, you don't reference implementation anywhere whitch causes dart to remove it during tree shaking.